# Error starting glassfish on port 80 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish

I'm having some trouble starting Glassfish on port 80 - doing so yields the following error:

> 0.0.0.0:80: initialize: name or service not known

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the internal host-resolution function (probably C's getaddrinfo) is not able to find the host 0.0.0.0.

Try entering in the exact IP in the configuration file, and re-running.

Usually you will get a Bind error instead, but also check to make sure no other services are using port 80: `netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep 80` That is a lowercase L.

Comment: And to find out which process is using port 80: sudo fuser -v -n tcp 80